# How to simplify Metal renderPass to draw 3 source textures to one destination texture

Tags: metal, metalkit

my input to frame rendering is three MTLTextures (identical size and type), three different viewports, and three different scissorRects. My vertexShader and fragmentShader are very simple (renders texture to quad). My current code creates three MTLRenderCommandEncoders in a loop for one buffer and commits the buffer. It works, but there must be a way to do the same using only one MTLRenderCommandEncoder. I started with:

```
- (void)setViewports:(const MTLViewport *)viewports count:(NSUInteger)count;
- (void)setScissorRects:(const MTLScissorRect *)scissorRects count:(NSUInteger)count;
```

, and I don't know how to set all three textures to the encoder. It could be:

```
- (void)setVertexTextures:(id<MTLTexture>  _Nullable const *)textures withRange:(NSRange)range;
```

but I don't know how the encoder passes (or how to pass) textures to shaders. Is encoder passing my array of MTLTextures at once to the shader and I have pickup the right one? Is there an option how to tell to the encoder to pass each texture (from the array) to shader? Or, do you have a better idea how to do it?

Thank you.

Comment: You set the attachments in the render pass descriptor. I don’t think  you can have different viewports for the same render pass

Comment: Attachments set in the render pass descriptor are destinations, not sources. I have three (or more) source textures and one destination (drawable.texture).

Answer (score 0):

It was easier than I thought. MTLRenderCommandEncoder encodes all drawing commands sequentially, in the order of how they are 'written' to the encoder until the endEncoding message is sent to the encoder.

Pseudo code for writing multiple textures to the same target texture:

```
_commandBuffer = [_commandQueue commandBuffer];
_drawableRenderDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].texture = drawable.texture;
_drawableRenderDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].loadAction = MTLLoadActionClear;
id <MTLRenderCommandEncoder> renderEncoder = [_commandBuffer renderCommandEncoderWithDescriptor: _drawableRenderDescriptor];
[renderEncoder setRenderPipelineState: _pipelineState];
[renderEncoder setVertexBuffer: _vertices offset: 0 atIndex: PPVertexInputIndexVertices];
    
for (id <MTLTexture> texture in textures){

    MTLScissorRect scissorRect = [self scissorRectForTexture: texture];
    MTLViewport viewPort = [self viewPortForTexture: texture];
    [renderEncoder setViewport: viewPort];
    [renderEncoder setScissorRect: scissorRect];
    [renderEncoder setFragmentTexture: region.texture atIndex: 0];
    [renderEncoder drawPrimitives: MTLPrimitiveTypeTriangle vertexStart: 0 vertexCount: _numVertices]; 
}

[renderEncoder endEncoding];
[_commandBuffer presentDrawable: drawable];
[_commandBuffer commit];
[_commandBuffer waitUntilScheduled];
```